# Find users, which are logged on the same Car

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table with Columns:

```
 ---------------------------+---------+----------------------------+--------+
 LogIn                      | CarNr   |LogOut                      | UserID | 
 ---------------------------+---------+----------------------------+--------+          
 2017-11-18-18.00.56.167000 | 7457518 | 2017-11-18-18.01.22.000000 | u39    |
 2017-11-18-18.01.10.443000 | 7456618 | 2017-11-18-18.01.22.000000 | u2     |
 2017-11-18-18.01.25.361000 | 7456586 | 2017-11-18-18.01.29.000000 | u64    |
 2017-11-18-18.01.32.008000 | 7456612 | 2017-11-18-18.01.49.000000 | u17    |
 2017-11-18-18.01.34.185000 | 7456257 | 2017-11-18-18.01.43.000000 | u2     |
 2017-11-18-18.01.49.247000 | 7456345 | 2017-11-18-18.02.16.000000 | u64    |
----------------------------+---------+----------------------------+---------+
```

In fact, the data is much more.

Is there any way to find all users which are logged in the same CarNr within one Minute?

I need SQL-Query to find these users.

Comment: This actually looks like a gaps and islands problem, where the islands are user records within one minute of one or more other records, with the same car.

Comment: add expected result for your current o/p ?

Comment: So you have a time and you want to know who is logged in the same car in that minute? Or you want all overlaps anytime? Add meaningful example with expected outputs to get good answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this;

**SQL Server**

```
select CarNr, DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, LogIn), LogIn) from Table 
group by CarNr, DATEADD(ms, -DATEPART(ms, LogIn), LogIn) having count(*) > 1
```

**MySQL**

```
select CarNr, DATE_ADD(LogIn, INTERVAL(-MICROSECOND(LogIn)) MICROSECOND) from Table 
group by CarNr, DATE_ADD(LogIn, INTERVAL(-MICROSECOND(LogIn)) MICROSECOND) having count(*) > 1
```

Just Group `LogIn` datetime by subtracting milliseconds.